# Handle login API token in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using following Login component:

```
var Login = Vue.extend({
    template: '#auth',
    data: function () {
        return {username: '',password: '',errorMessage:''};
    },
    methods : {
        login: function (e) {
            var _this = this;
            $.ajax({
                url: "/vue/api/login",
                type: "POST",
                async:false,
                data:{
                    username:_this.username,
                    password: _this.password
                },
                success: function (data) {
                // store the token in global variable ??
                    router.push({
                        path: '/employeeList',
                    });
                },
                error:function (xhr, status, error) {

                    _this.errorMessage = xhr.responseText
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The login API returns a token string for successful authentication. Should I store it in global variable or local storage ? Is there any filter that I can use to check if the user is logged in to application and then redirect accordingly?

Comment: Storage choice is up to you. Local storage allows saving login status after closing your page (cookies can be used too). Here is a good example of handling auth status with vue: https://auth0.com/blog/build-an-app-with-vuejs/

Answer (score 8):

The best way is by using [VUEX](http://vuex.vuejs.org/) : a vue state management system

In you vuex store.js file you can define the user's state as follows:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({ 
    state: { 
        user: {
            userName:'',
            loggedInStatus: true,
            authToken: ''
        }
    }, 
    mutations: { 
        addWebToken: function(state, webToken){
            state.user.authToken = webToken;
        },
        removeWebToken: function(state){
            state.user.authToken = '';
        }
    },
    actions: {
        login: function(context, userInput){
            $.ajax({
                url: "/vue/api/login",
                type: "POST",
                async:false,
                data:{
                    username:userInput.username,
                    password: userInput.password
                },
                success: function (data) {
                // store the token in global variable ??

                context.commit('addWebToken', webToken); // pass the webtoken as payload to the mutation

                    router.push({
                        path: '/employeeList',
                    });
                },
                error:function (xhr, status, error) {

                    _this.errorMessage = xhr.responseText
                }
            });
        },
        logput: function(context){
            //your logout functionality
            context.commit('removeWebToken');
        }
    }

})
```

now in your component >  methods > login() you can dispatch the login action you have declared in your vuex srore as follows

```
var Login = Vue.extend({
        template: '#auth',
        data: function () {
            return {username: '',password: '',errorMessage:''};
        },
        methods : {
            login: function () {
                //passing the username and password in an object as payload to the login action
                this.$store.dispatch('login', {username: this.username, ppassword: password});
            },
            logout: function(){
                this.$store.dispatch('logout');
            }
        }
    });
```

**the advantagess of doing so :**

- you have a centralized state where you can manage the user info in the state
- you can save the state in local store or as cookies using [vuex- persisted state](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate) as shown below, which would save the state of your user including the webtoken and even the state is persisted on page refreshes also. This means that when user is logged in and refreshes the page , since te user state from the store is kept you can access the webtoken and keep the user logged in.

`const store = new Store({
        // ... 
        plugins: [ createPersistedState({
            getState: (key) => Cookies.getJSON(key),
            setState: (key, state) => Cookies.set(key, state, { expires: 3, secure: true })
        }) ]
    })`

You can add the vuex persisted state plugin to your store and use jscookies library to save the state of your user in cookies or else local store if you want by following the [vuex-persistedstate documentation](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate)

Comment: Thanks for reply. That's what I am working on currently. Just read about Vuex 2.0. Will implement and revert back. +1

Comment: But does the current implementation stores it on local storage or just global variables ?

Comment: @VivekSadh the state of the vuex store is stored as Global variables you can use vuex persisted State and store this state as you require, i.e in local storage or cookies as you want